# What is the name of this chip on Arduino Mega ? I am not finding its datasheet 56 TI MSP?

Tags: arduino-mega

[image][image: IC Component]

What is the using purpose of this chip?

Comment: I think that says M5P not MSP - in which case it's IC5 - the LM358D op-amp used to control the USB power FET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one 8-pin SMD IC on the top side of the [Arduino Mega 2560](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mega-2560-rev3).

[image: Arduino Mega 2560]

From the [schematic](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/MEGA2560_Rev3e_sch.pdf)
it appears to be the "LMV358IDGKR" a TI dual op-amp used for two separate functions on the Mega.

- Selecting power source - VIN vs USB.
- Illuminating the built-in "L" LED (on D13) without loading PB7

Comment: I solved my problem with your help